# threshold or abs fucntion in python3

Tags: python, floating-point

I am learning the python3 from "How to think like a computer scientist: Learning with Python3". There is a exercise question, calclulate the right angle with this hint "threshold = 1e-7
if abs(x-y) < threshold:" 
I wrote this code. But I didn't undersrand that where and how I use hint instructions. In internet people used findHypot fucntion...

```
base = float(input("enter your base value in cm"))
per = float(input("enter your base value in cm"))
hyp = float(input("enter your base value in cm"))
if (base**2) + (per**2) == (hyp**2):
   print("true")
else:
   print("false")
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to numerical inaccuracy, you can't check for the equality of floats. You can only check if the difference between two floats becomes very small.

Therefore the hint, you should write something like:

```
base = float(input("enter your base value in cm"))
per = float(input("enter your base value in cm"))
hyp = float(input("enter your base value in cm"))
if abs((base**2) + (per**2) - (hyp**2))< 1e-7:
   print("true")
else:
   print("false")
```

Comment: thanks.....                                                                                                            
 Now I have to "Extend the above program so that the sides can be given to the function in any order " means taking input in angles or cm ??????

Comment: The hypotenuse will be the largest of the three values. The order of the other two doesn't matter, So if the user enters 3 values, take the largest to be the hypotenuse. If there are two equal values, and the other is smaller (ie there isn't a unique largest value) the triangle isn't a right triangle.

Comment: I used simply this technique                                                                                                          base = int(input("enter your base value in cm"))
per = int(input("enter your perpendicular value in cm"))
hyp = int(input("enter your hypoteneous value in cm"))
if (base**2) + (per**2) == (hyp**2):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false"

Comment: @learner but your solution doesn't work with non-integer distances, which should be handy here, as your solution would only work with pytagorean triples [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)